# Android app not showing up in Marketplace

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded my apk yesterday afternoon. Everything went fine, the app shows as 'Published', but I can't seem to find it in the Marketplace? I tried searching by package but no luck. What would be holding it up?

the package name is: com.icarus.creditcard

The app details page should be available here: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.icarus.creditcard but i just get a "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."

**UPDATE:**

for anyone that's interested, I submitted a ticket to google at the 2 day mark, they had it up the next day.

Comment: what is your application name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put my first app onto the Market it took about a day to appear. After that all apps are instant.

Comment: maybe patience is the answer!

Comment: On my side, updates are not instant. It seems the app totaly disappears from the market, before the new version show up a couple of hours later.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific phone ?
Maybe it's a big/small screen issue. Moreover maybe you put sdkversion restriction or stuff like this.

Look for more info here : http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Comment: Thanks, but I already checked that. In the developer console app details, I see:Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
android.hardware.telephony
android.hardware.touchscreen
This application is available to over 510 devices.

Comment: Are you sure you put it available in your country ? it seems a stupid question but i prefer to be sure anyway :)